# where I can put session except page load asp.net with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have created a webpage in which through session getting 3 database values from previous login page. Basically the current page use to book seat in bus. In which Mobile number is mandatory field. If mobile number is not entered seat cannot be booked. Through session I get 3 fields from table among them one is mobile number. If mobile number is already in the table no need to enter the mobile number. But if not there you have to enter mobile number to book seat as it is mandatory field. Now, the problem is when I tried to book seat I cannot able to book it, though I have entered mobile number. Always end up at "Please enter mobile number for successful booking...!!!"

Please refer below code :-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Label1.Text = Session["PERNR"].ToString();
    Label2.Text = Session["ZZFNAME"].ToString();
    TextBox1.Text = Session["MOBILE"].ToString();
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.Text == "Dahej to Baroda")
    {
        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox6.Text);
        string day = dt.DayOfWeek.ToString();
        if (dt >= DateTime.Now)
        {

            if (day == "Saturday")
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=10.127.240.216/ipcldb;User ID=ipcltos;Password=ipcltos;Unicode=True");
                con.Open();
                OracleDataAdapter a = new OracleDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM BARODA_BUS_BOOKING_DETAIL WHERE EMPCODE = '" + Label1.Text + "' AND JOURNEY_DATE='" + dt.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy") + "'", con);
                a.Fill(ds);
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    string display = "Already Booked...!!!";
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + display + "');", true);
                }
                else
                {

                    if(TextBox1.Text=="")
                    {
                        string display = "Please enter mobile number for successful booking...!!!";
                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + display + "');", true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO BARODA_BUS_BOOKING_DETAIL (EMPCODE,NAME,MOBILE,JOURNEY_TYPE,JOURNEY_DATE) VALUES('" + Label1.Text + "', '" + Label2.Text + "', '" + TextBox1.Text + "', '" + DropDownList1.Text + "','" + dt.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy") + "')", con);
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            string display = "Booked...!!!";
                            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + display + "');", true);
                            OracleCommand cmd1 = new OracleCommand("UPDATE SAP_EMPMST SET MOBILE = '" + TextBox1.Text + "' WHERE PERNR = '" + Label1.Text + "'", con);
                            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            con.Close();

                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {
                            string display = "Invalid Number...!!!";
                            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + display + "');", true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                string display = "Dahej to Baroda bus service available on Saturday only...!!!";
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + display + "');", true);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            string display = "You cannot book for the previous date...!!!";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + display + "');", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to keep the Session value in page load under !Ispostback and also are you clearing session value any where?

Comment: @Webruster didn't get u

Comment: please asign to textbox value under !ispostback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to keep everything in the **!Ispostback** because at the time of Postback the value for the **TextBox1.Text** will be lost

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
           Label1.Text = Session["PERNR"].ToString();
           Label2.Text = Session["ZZFNAME"].ToString();
           TextBox1.Text = Session["MOBILE"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Label1.Text = Session["PERNR"].ToString();
    Label2.Text = Session["ZZFNAME"].ToString();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = Session["MOBILE"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should place everything within the `!IsPostback`, not only `TextBox1.Text = Session["MOBILE"].ToString();`